Nginx is not working outside local network
I have a node.js server with express that serves an https web. The server is runing Windows 10. I have configured a no-ip ddns with ssl certificates. The web is on port 3000 and I want to start a reverse proxy with nginx to access it without having to specify the port, just the domain name. The problem is that nginx is working for local network machines but not external ones. This is the config for nginx:
worker_processes 1;
error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name servidordelacruz.dynns.com;

        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name xxxxxx.dynns.com;

        ssl_certificate      route_to\noip_fullchain_cert.pem; 
        ssl_certificate_key  route_to\cert.key;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:3000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}

I have ports 80 and 443 open on the router for the server and just for testing the windows firewall is disabled entirely.
I also confirmed the ddns is working since I also have a minecraft server that is accesible.
In the access.log file I can also see that the phone reaches the server:
X.X.X.X - - [05/Nov/2024:20:52:40 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Android 15; Mobile; rv:132.0) Gecko/132.0 Firefox/132.0"

Finally, in the errors. log file I see this error constantly:
2024/11/05 21:05:46 [info] 5276#10252: *943 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A000412:SSL routines::sslv3 alert bad certificate:SSL alert number 42) while SSL handshaking, client: X.X.X.X, server: 0.0.0.0:443

The client IP is my own public IP. I read that it might not be important though.

does ports 80 and 443 open on the router for the server mean port forwarding to the server?

yes, it is port forwarding

Alert 42 means "bad certificate"; "the phone" thinks your cert is invalid in some way. Either "the phone" is correct and your cert is bad, or your cert is good but "the phone" is wrong. Since you tell us nothing about either your cert or "the phone" and your address (83.58.36.169) does not respond on port 443 (port 80 does work) from my part of the world or from www.ssllabs.com/ssltest I can't provide any help, plus this doesn't look much like professional or business operation. ...

... If logged client addr in the log is your own addr then "the phone" is not actually connecting externally (maybe it's using your wifi?) and its ability to work at IP level could be due to 'hairpin NAT' while connections actually from outside don't work and won't work for anybody outside your residence.

See also this comment. So whatever the reason for this error, I don't think it is related to your main issue in any way.
